# Redirect domain names from linux dns server

Tags: linux, dns

So, the IT department decided to change a bunch of domain names and it broke a bunch of stuff in my lab network. I have a suse linux dns server (which I didn't setup and don't know much about). I was wondering if there was a way I could make it manually resolve ip addresses to the old domain names.
Simply modifying the software in my lab to point to the new domain names wont work (because there are other labs at other sites that will still be using the old domain names).

Comment: Do you know what program the suse machine uses to do it's DNS lookups?

Comment: What about just adding the old resolution to your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: but then he would have change the hosts file for all the machines affected

Comment: I thought of that, but there are hundreds of machines, and the OS may reinstalled on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some relevant quotes from [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/two_in_one_dns_bind9_views):

> Examples Corporation has been assigned the network 192.0.2.0/24 and internally we are using 10.0.0.0/24.
>
> Let's start serving the external names and IPs, we edit /etc/bind/named.conf.local4 and add:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};
```

> and then we create /etc/bind/db.example.com with the following contents:

```
; example.com
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. root.example.com. (
                     2006020201 ; Serial
                         604800 ; Refresh
                          86400 ; Retry
                        2419200 ; Expire
                         604800); Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1
        IN      MX      10 mail
        IN      A       192.0.2.1
ns1     IN      A       192.0.2.1
mail    IN      A       192.0.2.128 ; We have our mail server somewhere else.
www     IN      A       192.0.2.1
client1 IN      A       192.0.2.201 ; We connect to client1 very often.
```

So what you want to do is replace "example.com" with whatever domain your programs access, replace "192.0.2.whatever" with your destination ip and remove the "ns1", "mail", "www", "clien1" lines and replace it with

```
*.yourdomain.com. IN      A       your.ip.address.255
```